# ListView with Grouped Collection Header Click (Windows Store/Caliburn)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a ListView binded to CollectionViewSource which is Grouped. 
I want the header to be clickable, but how can I do that with MVVM - Caliburn?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Message.Attach](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions) syntax in this case. This is how you would modify the `DataTemplate` in `GroupedItemsPAge` from the `Grid App` project template:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
        <Button
            AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
            cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action OnHeaderClick($dataContext)]"
            Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

A header click will now call the `OnHeaderClick` method in your view model.

Comment: Thank you Damir! That worked. I was missing the dataContext parameter!